# Get the Contents of the Component Area Joomla

Tags: php, html, plugins, joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible to get the contents of the current page's `<jdoc:include type="component" />` area in a content plugin, and write it to a html file with `fwrite($ourFileHandle, $component);`

Comment: Not sure, but working alternative would be to enclose <jdoc:include type="component" /> in a div with some id, and then using javascript of your plugin capture it's content and send it via ajax to a php file which will save the content to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the component content by appending  `&tmpl=component` to the resource URL.

Example:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=viewname&tmpl=component
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have two events onBeforeContentPrepare() and onAfterContentPrepare() which both hold the content of the component, from there you can log to disk or even change the content.